# How can I export logs online from os monitoring tools?

Tags: monitoring

I need your experience in my topic.
I want to export logs from two or three operating system monitoring tools and analyze these logs and send a help message to user upon that state.
now i want two program and their methods to export logs online that i gather these data online in my database and use data for my program.
thank you for your answers!